# Powershell - Make a menu out of text file

Tags: powershell

In my adventure trying to learn Powershell, I am working on an extension on a script I have made. The idea is to make script there by adding ".iso" files into a folder. It will use that content in a menu so that I later can use it to select an *iso* file for a WM in Hyper-V

This is my version of how it will get the content in the first place

```
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\iso/*.iso -Name > C:\iso/nummer-temp.txt
Add-Content -Path C:\iso/nummer.txt ""
Get-Content -Path C:\iso/nummer-temp.txt | Add-Content -Path C:\iso/nummer.txt
```

When this code is run it will send an output like what i want. But my question is how do I use this output in a menu?

Comment: do you mean like you want it to see iso options in a graphical user interface ?

Comment: Yes I think. I would like it to look like
Windows10.iso
Windows8.iso

And if more is added they will then just be added I will then could tast 1 in a menu fuction and it will then select windows 10 for my WM in Hyper V

Comment: I got two options for you. one is to use the out-gridview command and the second one is to use system.windows.forms utilities from .NET framework in powershell. I will post a code snippet about them if needed.

Answer (score 0):

This is the best practice way to do so in powershell :

```bsh
#lets say your .txt files gets this list after running get-content



$my_isos = $('win7.iso','win8.iso','win10.iso')

$user_choice = $my_isos | Out-GridView -Title 'Select the ISO File you want'  -PassThru

#waiting till you choose the item you want from the grid view
Write-Host "$user_choice is going to be the VM"
```

I wouldn't try to make it with System.windows.forms utilities as i mentioned in my comment, unless you want to present the form more "good looking".

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to go for a graphical menu, but rather a console menu, you could use this function below:

```
function Show-Menu {
    Param(
        [Parameter(Position=0, Mandatory=$True)]
        [string[]]$MenuItems,
        [string] $Title
    )

    $header = $null
    if (![string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($Title)) {
        $len = [math]::Max(($MenuItems | Measure-Object -Maximum -Property Length).Maximum, $Title.Length)
        $header = '{0}{1}{2}' -f $Title, [Environment]::NewLine, ('-' * $len)
    }

    # possible choices: digits 1 to 9, characters A to Z
    $choices = (49..57) + (65..90) | ForEach-Object { [char]$_ }
    $i = 0
    $items = ($MenuItems | ForEach-Object { '{0}  {1}' -f $choices[$i++], $_ }) -join [Environment]::NewLine

    # display the menu and return the chosen option
    while ($true) {
        cls
        if ($header) { Write-Host $header -ForegroundColor Yellow }
        Write-Host $items
        Write-Host

        $answer = (Read-Host -Prompt 'Please make your choice').ToUpper()
        $index  = $choices.IndexOf($answer[0])

        if ($index -ge 0 -and $index -lt $MenuItems.Count) {
            return $MenuItems[$index]
        }
        else {
            Write-Warning "Invalid choice.. Please try again."
            Start-Sleep -Seconds 2
        }
    }
}
```

Having that in place, you call it like:

```
# get a list if iso files (file names for the menu and full path names for later handling)
$isoFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\IsoFiles' -Filter '*.iso' -File | Select-Object Name, FullName
$selected = Show-Menu -MenuItems $isoFiles.Name -Title 'Please select the ISO file to use'
# get the full path name for the chosen file from the $isoFiles array
$isoToUse = ($isoFiles | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq $selected }).FullName

Write-Host "`r`nYou have selected file '$isoToUse'"
```

Example:

> ```
> Please select the ISO file to use
> ---------------------------------
> 1  Win10.iso
> 2  Win7.iso
> 3  Win8.iso
>
> Please make your choice: 3
>
> You have selected file 'D:\IsoFiles\Win8.iso'
> ```